# how to use pygrib expand_reduce functionality?

Tags: python, gfs, pygrib

I am using pygrib to open GFS data, I want the data to be in unstructured format (not the default option). in short, **How can I set expand_reduce to False?**

```
grbs = pygrib.open(filename)
print(grbs[1].expand_reduce) # this prints True (default)
```

In the docs (https://jswhit.github.io/pygrib/api.html) it says:

> @ivar expand_reduced:  If True (default), reduced lat/lon and gaussian grids
> will be expanded to regular grids when data is accessed via "values" key. If
> False, data is kept on unstructured reduced grid, and is returned in a 1-d
> array.

I took a look at the source code (https://searchcode.com/file/11567389/pygrib.pyx/) and found that  it is a private attribute, and that it is hard coded in the _create_gribmessage method.

```
 625 cdef _create_gribmessage(grib_handle *gh, object messagenumber):
 626    """factory function for creating gribmessage instances"""
 627    cdef gribmessage grb  = gribmessage.__new__(gribmessage)
 628    grb.messagenumber = messagenumber
 629    grb.expand_reduced = True   ## HERE <---
 630    grb._gh = grib_handle_clone(gh)
 631    grb._all_keys = grb.keys()
 632    grb._ro_keys  = grb._read_only_keys()
 633    grb._set_projparams() # set projection parameter dict.
 634    return setdates(grb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call expand_grid, this will modify the expand_reduced:

```
grbs[1].expand_grid(False)
print(grbs[1].expand_reduce) # this now prints False
```